# Switching between activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-intent

In an given Android activity, I would like to start a new activity for the user at some point. Once they leave the first activity and arrive at the second, the first activity is hidden..

Now my question is

I want to bring back the first activity (i dont want to create a new instance of the first activity but to bring back the already existing instance of the first activity) when a button is clicked in the second activity ...

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so simple. integrate the below code in your second activity

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(yourbuttonid here);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        finish();
    }
});
```

This will work

Comment: :) will take care of that from next :)

Answer (score 1):

You would [define the first activity with `launchMode="singleInstance"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes), then you would start the activity as usual.

Comment: this works, or you can just call `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);` before calling startActivity

Comment: No DO NOT do this.  "singleInstance" has all kinds of repercussions on the activity stack management.  The original poster didn't ask for these, and unless you actually want them you should NOT use this.  The previous reply of using finish() works perfectly well for what is being requested, and doesn't mess up other behavior of the app.  (One example: if the user leaves the app with the home button, and returns to it with the task switcher or by relaunching from its icon in the home screen, if you use singleInstance then only the first activity will be brought to the foreground.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the usage of your second activity, you could also use `startActivityForResult()` when you start your second activity...

Answer (score 0):

FirstActivity.java{

private static final int SECOND_ACTIVITY = 0;

openSecondActivity(){

Intent forChildIntent= new  Intent( this ,FirstActivity. class );
//data for second activity
forChildIntent.putExtra("userName", getUsrName());
this.startActivityForResult(forChildIntent, SECOND_ACTIVITY);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
switch (resultCode) {

```
    case RESULT_OK:  //do something

            default:break;
```

}

}

---

SecondActivity.java{

goBackButtonClick(){
Intent retData=new Intent();

//set data to pass back ,if required 
//retData.putExtra("userName", getUsrName());

setResult(RESULT_OK, retData);

finish();//will take you to the first activity

}

}